# Kotlin, WebView: How to set my page of ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Tags: android, kotlin

When I shut down wifi at my mobile phone and I click to the some link in WebView, I see this error: ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

How to set myself error page? I searched solution too many days but I don't see 2023 solution.
Not works: onReceivedError, onReceivedHttpError, ...

I'm using Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code after on Page finished

Java:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
           //Your code to do
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + error.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // or you can show the error layout for example
    }
```

Kotlin:

```
override fun onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
                //Your code to do
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + error.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
// or show the error layout for example
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your code but it not works. I got it after onPageFinished. But I see function yellow in this place. I tried many other places but the name of function is yellow only here

Comment: On Page finished? Do you mean onPageFinished? Function onReceivedError not works in onPageFinished.

Comment: it's after onPageFinished not in it @djlj

Comment: Thanks! But my code: override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, weburl: String) { ... @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M) ........... override fun onReceivedError( view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceError ) { ... so where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It must be like this right now:

```
    val webView = WebView(this)
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onReceivedError(
            webView: WebView,
            errorCode: Int,
            description: String,
            failingUrl: String
        ) {
            try {
                webView.stopLoading()
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            }
            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack()
            }
            webView.loadUrl("about:blank")
            val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity).create()
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error")
            alertDialog.setMessage("❗ Internet not works ❗")
            alertDialog.setButton(
                DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "TRY AGAIN"
            ) { dialog, which ->
                finish()
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            alertDialog.show()
            super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl)
        }
    }
```

There is big change in Kotlin. Old versions of onReceivedError not works but this works.